# How to find all non blank cells in an array of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data in **$A$1:$D$50**. How can I put all non blank cells into a single column (say **E**) using a formula (regular or array one). All other examples I've found were about finding blank cells in a single column or a row.

Thanks

Comment: If A1, B1, C1, and D1 are all non-blank, how would you place them all in E1 together? Without knowing what you are trying to do, it isn't clear what the solution would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enter the following UDF:

```
Public Function NonBlanks(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim c As Collection, r As Range, CC As Long, i As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
        c.Add (r.Value)
        End If
    Next r
    CC = c.Count
    ReDim Arout(1 To CC, 1 To 1) As Variant
    For i = 1 To CC
        Arout(i, 1) = c(i)
    Next i
    NonBlanks = Arout
End Function
```

Then select E1 thru E200 and enter the following **array formula**

**=NonBlanks(A1:D50)**

**EDIT#1**:

Without VBA, pick a "helper" column, say column **F**.  In **F1** enter:

```
=IF(OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-1,50),INT((ROW()-1)/50))="","",OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-1,50),INT((ROW()-1)/50)))
```

and copy down thru **F200**

Then apply your standard formula to column **F**

**EDIT#2**:

**REFERENCE:**

By standard formula I mean something like  [Pearson's method](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/noblanks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I should avoid using VBA in my workbook. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Sure.........brute force......map the block of cells into a single "helper" column and then use standard formulas on the "helper" column.

Comment: I don't know how to map them into a single helper column. (That's what I'm looking for.) Would you mind explaining it.

Comment: Thanks again Gary's Student!